# Why after creating a JFrame object and setting it as visible, the program will not end executing?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, concurrency

My program looks like this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I'm just confused why after JVM's quitting from main(), my program does not end instantly? I noticed that if I remove the line "jf.setVisible(true);", it will end.

Is it implemented though techniques like garbage collecting or class destructors? I'm interested that if I want to write something similar, how could I do it.

Comment: Change exit on close to dispose on close and it'll work. I believe the exit flag is depreciated.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell: I believe you're wrong. Where have you read that JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE is deprecated? Here is the [Java 7 JFrame API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html). Again, please show me where it's deprecated.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels It appears you are correct. I couldn't find out where EXIT_ON_CLOSE was said to be deprecated. I must of confused it with all the articles talking about to never use it, since it forces a System.exit() to be called. I take it back, not deprecated, just very poorly implemented.

Comment: Swing GUIs should be created and updated on the EDT.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason is that when  you call setVisible(true) on the JFrame, behind the scenes a non-daemon thread is started, and the JVM will not exit until all non-daemon threads terminate.

Please have a look here for more on [AWT/Swing Threading issues](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/AWTThreadIssues.html).
It states:

> "There is at least one alive non-daemon thread while there is at least one displayable AWT or Swing component within the application (see [Component.isDisplayable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isDisplayable()))."

While this is for Java 1.5, I think that it is still valid information.

Also, I believe that the Event Dispatch Thread or EDT is not a daemon thread, and so it is another thread associated with Swing that drives this.

**Edit 1**
This suggests that the EDT is in fact a non-Daemon thread:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class IsEdtDaemon {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             JFrame frame = new JFrame();
             frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
             frame.setVisible(true);

             System.out.printf("Is the current thread the EDT thread: %b%n",  SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
             System.out.printf("Is our EDT Thread a daemon thread:    %b%n",  Thread.currentThread().isDaemon());
         }
      });
   }
}
```

The output from the code is:

> Is the current thread the EDT thread: true
>   Is our EDT Thread a daemon thread:    false

Comment: I'm less sure of that now.  I can find nothing to support *or* refute it.

Comment: *"While this is for Java 1.5,.."*  See also http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/doc-files/AWTThreadIssues.html  (change '1.5.0' to '7').

Comment: @AndrewThompson: My SSCCE above shows that the EDT is in fact a non-daemon thread, but this of course does not answer the question for the generalized case, but rather just for the 64 bit Windows 7 case.

Comment: +1 nice example (tells us the answer for at least 1 set-up), excellent conclusion (does not presume that result will be the same for other set-ups).

Answer (score 0):

When you create the JFrame and make it visible you've created an implicit event listener that is now waiting for an action. If you hadn't set the default close action you would've needed to provide some other way for the application to "know" it can exit.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not call `jf.setVisible(true)` then your program does construct the JFrame, sets it's dimensions and defines the default close operation, but never draws the JFrame on screen and so it exits. It wouldn't make any sense to create a JFrame if you do not want to ever make it visible.

The behavior one expects from a top-level container like JFrame, would be after setting it to visible to stay up and be used, until someone clicks on the close button which happens because of the `jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);` setting.

Just think about what goes on with any application, i.e. your browser. It starts and stays up until you press the close button or exit the application in another way.